# Add css to only homepage from xml in magento

Tags: css, xml, magento

Want to include css file which is applicable to only homepage from xml file.
Tried this :

```
<cms_index_index>
 <action add css>
   .
   .
 </action> 
</cms_index_index>
```

using this in local.xml adds that particular css in every cms page.
Any Idea ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: need more info.

Is your home page is content or static block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the cms home page there is Design(Layout Update XML)
use the following code in that

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/myjavascript.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 4):

this solution work for me

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
             <reference name="head">
                  <action method="addCss">
                     <stylesheet>
                               css/custom.css /*This is ur css path*/
                     </stylesheet>
                  </action>
             </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="your cms identifier for home page">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>your path/your css file name</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Please use this code in `local.xml` or `page.xml`

Am not 100% sure  about the code work or not

Comment: The <cms_index_index> is what identifies the home page ... the <reference name=""> is to indicate the structural block you want to act on - in this instance that would be <reference name="head">

Answer (score 1):

In combination with @Leo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414845/63609) as well as [another blog post](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout) I found recently, here's a code snippet to add custom css to just a single page only.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Same instructions as @Leo mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The above suggestions didn't work for me in Magento 1.7, blank theme. What worked was this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCSS">
      <type>css/master.css</type>
      <stylesheet>media="all"</stylesheet>
    </action>
  </reference>
```

This produced the following code

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myshop.com/shop/skin/frontend/mytheme/blank/css/master.css" media="all"></head>
```

I placed this code into the local.xml of my theme.